# Count rings of incoming call in android

Tags: android

I am designing an application in android which will give response to incoming call.
For that I want to **count ring of incoming call **(i.e how many time the phone has rung yet). I tried searching it but did not find any clue. I want to respond to the incoming call after ringing the phone for some specific number of times. I tried to catch incoming call state but it did not let me to achieve that.
Please help me to come out from this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide some proper help. How can I count number of ring that are heard by caller in incoming call i.e. at Callie side.

Comment: Where you able yo figure out this?

Answer (score 0):

You could wait for a timer to expire when you receive the state change indicating that a call is being received.